# Pointer Casting/Conversion Solution Upgrading C to C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, void-pointers

I'm modifying a C source file (`libape-spidermonkey.c`).  I include a lib header file that uses some C++ features (such as, `class definitions`, `STL string vector`), so I have to compile `libape-spidermonkey.c` using `g++` instead of `gcc`.

However, because of the type-checking in C++, I got a lot of errors (NOT warnings):

```
libape-spidermonkey.c: In function ‘JSBool ape_sm_raw_constructor(JSContext*, JSObject*, uintN, jsval*, jsval*)’:
libape-spidermonkey.c:2217:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_sm_compiled*’
libape-spidermonkey.c: In function ‘JSBool ape_sm_sockclient_constructor(JSContext*, JSObject*, uintN,
libape-spidermonkey.c:2231:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_sm_compiled*’
libape-spidermonkey.c:2244:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘_ape_sock_js_obj*’
libape-spidermonkey.c:2248:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘_ape_sock_callbacks*’
libape-spidermonkey.c:2257:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_socket*’
libape-spidermonkey.c: In function ‘JSBool ape_sm_pipe_constructor(JSContext*, JSObject*, uintN, jsval*
libape-spidermonkey.c:2281:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_sm_compiled*’
libape-spidermonkey.c: In function ‘JSBool ape_sm_sockserver_constructor(JSContext*, JSObject*, uintN,
libape-spidermonkey.c:2585:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_sm_compiled*’
libape-spidermonkey.c: In function ‘JSBool ape_sm_xorize(JSContext*, JSObject*, uintN, jsval*, jsval*)’
libape-spidermonkey.c:2632:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘ape_sm_compiled*’
libape-spidermonkey.c:2646:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
libape-spidermonkey.c:2650:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
```

Is there any easy way to solve this issue? Like some macro magic?

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: What kind of g++ options you have? Did you enabled -Werror -Wall? If yes then try to disable -Werror for this file.

Comment: What C++ features are in the header file? Post some of the code that has errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile that file as a C file, rather than a C++ file. C and C++ objects can be linked together without problems.

Comment: But I added a lib header file that uses some C++ features, so I have to compile it using C++.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: So long as you didn't change the C to use C++ features, you can still compile as C. Alternately, you'll have to add in a bunch of `static_cast`s.

Comment: you are right.  I finally found out that, the APE project does provide an interface for C++ lib loading without changing their source code (though it's completely NOT documented).  Therefore, I separated my logic from the original project, and compiled it using C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice (even for C developers) to try to compile their C codes using a C++ compiler. The errors found by the C++ compiler will help you to improve your code quality.

So I'd recommend you to fix the errors in your libape-spidermonkey.c using C style casting (and not the C++ static_casts). That will garantee that your code will still compile in C compilers if you need that in the future.